# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and trying to make a simple web app.

I generated the following components:

```rb
rails generate scaffold user username:string password:string
```

```rb
rails generate scaffold appointment doctor:references patient:references
```

and in the appointment model I specified the class for doctor and patient to be users like below

```rb
# app/models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :patient, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I left everything else to be the same, by applying `rails db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare`, I got this error message saying I don't have the table doctor

```rb
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.doctors
```

But I thought the specification in appointment.rb would do the job for me.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaffold most probably generated a migration with a `foreign_key: true` on the references.

Check create_appointments migration file in `db/migrate/` and remove it.

If you want to have a foreign key add:

```
add_foreign_key :appointments, :users, column: :doctor_id
add_foreign_key :appointments, :users, column: :patient_id
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key

The foreign key constraint checks if the id that you are setting is present in the other table. If it is not, it will crash when you create a record.

Comment: can you tell me more about removing the `foreign_key: true`? they are indeed foreign_keys, aren't they?

Comment: The migration files describe changes to your database. The `foreign_key: true` tells it to add a standard foreign key constraint  -> google it ;) https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

By default it will use the column name a.k.a. doctor_id and will try to guess the table -> doctors.

To tell it to add the constraint against a different table  at the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

`doctor: references` and `patient: references` will create two columns in the `appointments` table with `doctor_id` and `patient_id` which will reference `doctors` table and `patients` table respectively.

No surprise here, these tables don't exist. To tell the migration that `doctor` and `patient` are actually from `users` table you need to use `to_table` in your migration:

Open the appointments migration file in `db/migrate/` and add `to_table` option for both patient references and doctor references:

```rb
t.references :doctor, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }, index: true
t.references :patient, foreign_key: { to_tabale: :users }, index: true
```

`to_table` is used when you want to make a column reference a different table.